# How to use Zend Helper in Lithium

Tags: zend-framework, lithium

i'm trying to migrate my cakephp apps to lithium, and already use Doctrine, and Twig as plugin, but now i'm also want to integrate Zend libraries into apps, and i have to integrate the Zend helper libraries.

I added the Zend library and ZendX on bootstrap, and i already can acessed the libraries in controller. But my problem is how to call helper like ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper_AjaxLink in view. So in view i can call like this :

```
<?php echo $this->ajaxLink("Show me something",
                "/hello/world",
                array('update' => '#content'));?>
```

it's possible to integrate those without touch anything in Zend Helper class?

Comment: These are Zend_View helpers, which means you can use them together with Zend_View.

Comment: @markus i think so, in the documentation, the helper is tighly integrate with view, like must to register helper and etc. I plan to make a Lithium Helper as wrapper, but i'm still don't get it the Zend_View mechanism, calling ->ajaxLink(..) in wrapper doesn't give right output.

Answer (score 1):

Using Zend components in other frameworks based projects is generally very simple, except when it comes to components related to Zend's MVC or bootstrapping stack.

I would recommend that you take inspiration from the Zend's view helpers you're interested in and code your own Lithium view helpers. [Here is a simple tutorial about writing Lithium view helpers](http://www.nitschinger.at/Write-your-own-Helper-with-Lithium), it could perhaps help you.